# Getting DocumentSteam for html websites without using a Winforms WebBrowser control for parsing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parsing

Getting DocumentSteam for html websites without using a Winforms WebBrowser control for parsing?

Is this possible? I would like to create some types like:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument ("http://www.ms.com");
DocumentStream ds = doc.GetFullStream();

...
```

Also if possible, please post code.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use WebClient:

```
    String url = "http://www.ms.com";
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();

    // Add a user agent header in case the 
    // requested URI contains a query.

    client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    Stream data = client.OpenRead (url);
    //Do stuff here
    //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
    //string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    //Console.WriteLine (s);
    data.Close ();
    reader.Close ();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very good code, it works. Do you know if it's possible ot retirive the page as if I am using IE? It seems like this doesn't use IE cookies, which makes sense, but the link I am visiting is a forum and it would be great if I can visit it as if I am logged in. Is that possible?

Comment: You would need to create your own HttpRequest and setup the associated cookie container for that.

Comment: Yeah, Simon is right you need to use HttpRequest to setup cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for html parsing, instead of an ui element?

Comment: Thanks, does it return the html stream of the url I will pass to it?

Comment: I do not know what type of stream you're after. HTML Agility Pack will provide you with a parsed DOM-structure for html, just like System.Xml does for xml. This is a excellent tool for parsing html, but if you just want to read the html content of a page as a string, use the WebClient class as previously mentioned.